Basic error encountered when trying to run PyTorch in Google Colab
I just started learning Deep Learning with PyTorch on DataCamp and I take my notes in Google Colab. This code is supposed to create a basic neural network, and it works well on DataCamp's servers, but I encounter an error whenever I try to run it on Google Colab.
The way that DataCamp teaches you how to do this is to create a variable (e.g., model), that stores the NN sequence. Then you call the variable with the input tensor in parentheses, similar to how you call a function. This seems to match how some examples do it on Github, but it confuses Google Colab. I feel that the answer here is quite basic, but how do I fix this?
Code:
input_tensor = torch.tensor([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]])
model = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(8, 15),
                      nn.Linear(15, 1)
                     )

output = model(input_tensor)
print(output)

Error Message:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-1092509e4a88> in <cell line: 6>()
      4                      )
      5 
----> 6 output = model(input_tensor)
      7 print(output)

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/linear.py in forward(self, input)
    114 
    115     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 116         return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
    117 
    118     def extra_repr(self) -> str:

RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 must have the same dtype, but got Long and Float

I've checked examples on Github and they're also coded the way that I'm doing it.

The solution is to change input tensor dtype:
input_tensor = torch.tensor(
    [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]],
    dtype = torch.float32
    )

